Running cypress headless .then timed out after waiting `4000ms`
I have this bit of Cypress code that clicks a button and it navigates to the url that's on the clipboard.
cy.get('.process-list').within(() => {
    cy.get('.process-list-item').eq(3).within(() => {
        cy.get('.nakedButton').eq(0).click();
        cy.wait(1000);
    });
});

cy.window().then(win => {
    return win.navigator.clipboard.readText().then(text => {
        cy.log(text).then(() => {
            cy.visit(text);
        });
    });
});

This works fine when I run it via cypress desktop ui. When I run the test in headless mode on chrome via power shell, I get the following error:
CypressError: cy.then() timed out after waiting 4000ms.
Your callback function returned a promise that never resolved.
The callback function was:
win => {
    return win.navigator.clipboard.readText().then(text => {
      cy.log(text).then(() => {
        text = text.replace("https://", "http://");
        cy.visit(text);
      });
    });
  }

Any recommendations on how to resolve this so it passes when it runs in headless mode? Thank you.

Generally you can't read the clipboard in Cypress. Could you show the whole log, and which browser are you using.

The code produces the error (uncaught exception)NotAllowedError: Failed to execute 'readText' on 'Clipboard': Document is not focused.

I fixed the issue by adding this package to my project:
npm install cypress-clipboard;

Add this using statement to your test:
import 'cypress-clipboard';

Add this code to your cypress test, it assigns the clipboard the read/write permission:
cy.wrap(Cypress.automation('remote:debugger:protocol', {
    command: 'Browser.grantPermissions',
    params: {
        permissions: ['clipboardReadWrite', 'clipboardSanitizedWrite'],
        origin: window.location.origin
    },
}));

The test works fine now when running headless via PowerShell and when running via cypress ui.

Try using stub to capture the clipboard content as it is written during the click.
This way you can separate the visit from the readText() promise and avoid the Cypress error.
cy.visit('/', {
  onBeforeLoad: (win) => {
    cy.stub(win.navigator.clipboard, 'writeText').as('clipboard')
  },
})

cy.get('.process-list')
  .find('.process-list-item').eq(3)
  .find('.nakedButton').eq(0).click();

cy.get('@clipboard').then(url => {
  cy.visit(url)
})


If read the documentation for package cypress-clipboard you see it provides custom commands for example
import 'cypress-clipboard';

cy.wrap('SOME STRING VALUE')
    .copyToClipboard(); 

But unfortunately if you try to use it with current chrome browser which is v127 you get this error

It's because there is no longer the option to set permissions to the clipboard from inside a Cypress test.
See this section Security considerations

The specification requires that a user has recently interacted with the page in order to read from the clipboard (transient user activation is required).

